# How can I route SSH traffic based on a subdomain?

Tags: ssh, routing, reverse-proxy

I have a home server running ubuntu 10.04 that is running two services:

1. an SSH service
2. a dockerized gogs service

I would like to essentially reverse-proxy incoming SSH connections based on the subdomain.  For instance, I'd like for ssh connections made via `ssh user@mydomain.com` to be forwarded to port `2222` and those made via `ssh user@gogs.mydomain.com` to be forwarded to port `10022`.

In essence, I'd like something analogous to nginx for SSH traffic.  How can this be achieved?

Comment: See [Do the SSH or FTP protocols tell the server to which domain I am trying to connect?](http://serverfault.com/a/672403/168875)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is impossible. SSH has no notion of a Host header as is present in HTTP. The best you can do is port-based routing.

Comment: Bad news, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: @blz I managed to patch the OpenSSH client to work through a name based HTTP proxy. It is [dirty as hell](http://share.kasperd.net/openssh-6.6p1-host-header.patch) and will not work with all proxies. You should be using IPv6 instead.

Comment: @kasperd, thanks for the link and for the full disclosure!  I'll look into it carefully :)