# Set up FTP on IIS7

Tags: ftp, iis-7

I have been breaking my head over this seemingly simple problem. I want to provide FTP access to specific folder to a specific user on my server. This is what I did.

- Create a new user, let's call him John
- Gave new user (John) full permissions on the folder that I want to open up. Let's call the folder `myfolder`
- In IIS7 create a new FTP site: Add new FTP site. I set `myfolder` as the Home Directory. As far as bindings, I pick all unassigned IP's, port 21 and a specific subdomain/ domain that points to this server. I checked that.
- In the next screen, for Authentication, I check `Basic Authentication` and I grant read / write access to `specific users`, in this case `John.`

I have played around with some of the other settings as well, but whatever I do, I get the same error:

> 530 User cannot log in, home directory inaccessible.

No need to mention, I checked the Windows permissions on that folder 100 times over. User `John` has full access to folder `myfolder.`

Using Windows Server 2008 R2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

I already had a working FTP site on that server with the same IP in the bindings. And I was trying to create a second FTP site, with a different hostname. I thought that IIS would be smart enough to be able to differentiate based on the settings in the bindings.

e.g.

> FTPsite1: bindings: IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Port: 21 host: ftp1.mysite.com - authorized user: user1
>
> FTPsite2: bindings: IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Port: 21 host: ftp2.mysite.com - authorized user: user2

You can do this, however, the way to log in is different than what I expected.

To log in to Site 1:

```
ftp> open ftp1.mysite.com
Connected to ftp.interbayrotary.org.
220 Microsoft FTP Service
Name (ftp1.mysite.com:user): ftp1.mysite.com|user1
Password:
```

So your user name needs to be of the following format `host|username.` And that is the only way it will work.

If you just enter `user1` as the user, you will get a `530` error, even though you clearly connect to the right site, based on the bindings settings.

This [article](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-the-ftp-service/using-ftp-virtual-host-names-in-iis-7) from Microsoft explains how to set up virtual hosts.

And this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2007/08/28/virtual-hosts-and-host-names-in-ftp7.aspx) specifically talks about the `hostname|username` syntax.

Comment: Of course, as the command-line `ftp.exe` client does not automatically send the `HOST` command. See also [Do the SSH or FTP protocols tell the server to which domain I am trying to connect?](http://serverfault.com/a/672403/168875).

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the right for your user in security tab too of your folder properties

more detail there: https://en.wiki.frogg.fr/Microsoft_IIS#FTP

Comment: I did that, @Froggiz. However, that brings up another question. In the example link that you provide, in the Authorized users windows, the user is specified via their email address? Why is that?

Comment: nice, that s an error, i am use to set ftp user linked to email, but it doesn't work on IIS :P, i correct this soon !

Comment: "No need to mention, I checked the Windows permissions on that folder 100 times over. User John has full access to folder myfolder." --- your answer is not the solution to my problem.

Comment: did you checked your firewall server side (opened port 21) ? did you tried passive mode to connect ?

Comment: @Froggiz Firewall/passive mode cannot have any effect on "User cannot log in, home directory inaccessible" error.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, yeah I did not think so either. Anyways, I am able to connect to the same server, but different user and different folder just fine.

Comment: it was just some advice, error on graphical ftp client are not all the time revelant

Comment: did you checked : http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configuring-ftp-user-isolation-in-iis-7 and http://xpertnotes.net/blog/2014/03/21/iis-7-5-ftp-530-user-cannot-log-in-home-directory-inaccessible/

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I found the answer to my problem FWIW.