# Configure multiple FTP serves using single public IP

Tags: ftp, configuration

I have around 3 internal FTP servers named `server1`, `server2`, `server3`. I have 1 public static IP address and all the traffic for `example.com` is directed towards it.

Now I need to create a configuration such that if user FTP using `ftp://server1.example.com` it should land on `server1` and if user FTP using `ftp://server2.example.com` it should land on `server2`.

I am not sure how can I achieve this. I tried using Squid but it does not work for FTP as FTP does not have concept of host.

Comment: Crush FTP can do this, also supports a lot of extra features like remote directories

Comment: I downloaded crush ftp but I could only find the option for configuring reverse proxy for HTTP not FTP. If you are certain then I can have a second look into it.

Comment: you ftp to crush, then crush can ftp to your internal systems, typically with user mapping (add remote folders under user account properties)

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because FTP doesn't have something like the HOST header that makes this possible with HTTP, as you noted yourself.

What would work for some use cases (obviously not  for anon ftp) is to mount the storage of the "backend" servers to the frontend server via NFS and then have user names with "home directories" that point to the NFS mount points. The frontend would do the actual FTP transfers but it gets the disk space from the backend servers.

Comment: Thanks Sven, seems like the solution you provided will work and I will try that. It will involve more overhead of configuring systems whenever a new user is added but seems like that is the only option. I am not sure how these web hosting companies like bluehost or arvixe host the ftp servers. Do they use static IP for all their internal servers.

Comment: That's not entirely correct, there is an RFC to implement this. However I don't think it is widely adopted yet (see: http://serverfault.com/a/672403/56431)

Comment: @faker: Interesting to know and to keep an eye out for future developments, but at this point, I would consider having this for SSH much more desirable. I can't even remember when I last used an FTP server (except possible download links in web pages).