# How to check which DNS Alias is used to access the server?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, logging, cname-record, alias

I have a host with a database installed on it.
In order to access the database, the clients use a DNS Alias (CNAME) - AliasOne - and the database port.

DNS Aliases are managed by colleagues in another department.

I had to request a more explicit alias - AliasTwo - for the same host.

Now: 
**I need to delete AliasOne : how can I check which Alias is used to connect on the host/to the database ?**

- I don't get this information in the database logs.
- I tried to create an iptables rule :

> iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s AliasOne --dport 3306 -j LOG
>   --log-prefix "AliasOne:   " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options

but it translates the alias with its hostname, thus, it will also log the connection attempts of AliasTwo.

- I didn't manage to get the answer with nslookup, dig, last. Am I using them wrong ?

Any clue anybody ? 
(I don't want a service interruption, so "delete and see if somebody complains" is not an option ;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the protocol explicitly mandates the inclusion of a hostname in the handshake/requests you can't determine from the server which hostname the client uses to connect.  The client simply connects to the ip-address that hostname or alias resolves to. (See [this Q&A](https://serverfault.com/questions/878080/how-do-i-make-protocol-foo-hostname-aware) for more background details.)

And as far as I know MySQL does not include hostnames in the handshake https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/connection-phase.html

One work-around may be to configure the server (temporarily) with an extra ip-address and point each hostname/alias to a different ip-address and then  the ip-address used will  determine the hostname used. Alternatively monitor your DNS servers and register lookups for the deprecated alias.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.
I though I could do it with standard CLI commands but the solution with a temporary host, and an iptables packets forward + logging did the job.