# Are name based virtual hosts for non-web servers?

Tags: virtualhost

Does [the concept of name based virtual host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting) only apply to web server? Or also to other servers which are  not web servers?

I ask this because in web servers, named based virtual hosts are implemented by HTTP Host header. I don't see virtual hosts for non-web servers.

Thanks.

Comment: If you hover over the "virtualhost" tag you will see that the Tag Wiki says in part "can also cover other protocols such as SMTP or IMAP." :-)

Comment: I meant  "named based virtual hosts". Sorry for missing it in the title

Comment: The protocol itself must support it. Of course, name based virtual hosting is merely a workaround for the shortage of IPv4 addresses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make protocol foo hostname-aware?](https://serverfault.com/questions/878080/how-do-i-make-protocol-foo-hostname-aware) which explains that such a thing exists for email and FTP as well.