# Multiple servers behind one public IP

Tags: reverse-proxy, domain, internal-dns, powerdns, traffic-management

I am hosting multiple servers behind one public IP. (Mostly in Proxmox VE) Currently, all the services are on separate ports.
I would like to use multiple domains to reach different services and am not sure how/ if I can do this.

I have looked at squid reverse proxy but it only works with HTTP/HTTPS

I'm not sure if a local DNS could help. Although I am planning on setting up a local PowerDNS server anyway.

Comment: Please provide more information. Which protocol is used to access the services? If you have two domains that resolve to the same IP address, you need a protocol, such as HTTP, that allows the service to see to which domain a request was made. If your protocol does not have that feature, I don't think there is a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make protocol foo hostname-aware?](https://serverfault.com/questions/878080/how-do-i-make-protocol-foo-hostname-aware)

Comment: As the linked duplicate explains: it really depends on the protocol if that is at all possible.